# Reading PDF/text/word file efficiently with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, file-format

I am doing NLP (Natural Language Processing) processing on my data. The data is in form of files that can be of type PDF/Text/Word/HTML. These files are stored in a nested directory structure on local disk.

My stand alone Java based NLP parser can read input files, extract text from these and do the NLP processing on the extracted text.

I am converting my Java based NLP parser to execute it on my Spark cluster. I know that Spark can read multiple text files from a directory and convert into RDDs for further processing. My input data is not only in text files, but in a multitude of different file formats.

My question is: How can I efficiently read the input files (PDF/Text/Word/HTML) in my Java based Spark program for processing these files in Spark cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Files can be read by

```
sparkContext.binaryFiles()
```

And then can be processed by parser.